# ¿Se puede hacer una clase que "contenga" otras clases?

Tags: c#

Por ejemplo:

```
public class A {
    //propiedades y metodos
} 
public class B {
    //propiedades y metodos
} 
// y luego: 
public class classContainer { 
    public A class1 {get; set;} 
    public B class2 {get; set;}
}
```

¿Cómo accedería a las propiedades de mis clases A y B desde la clase Container?

Comment: pues únicamente llamarlas... al ser locales solo necesitas llamar a class1. y class2 , si tienes otras clases con ese nombre puedes utilizar el this para ser mas especifico

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un comentario de estilo: los nombres de clases y propiedades en C# se suelen escribir en mayúsculas. Tampoco parece demasiado apropiado usar el nombre "class1" para una propiedad... se presta a confusiones.

Si tu clase "container" fuera esta:

```
public class ClassContainer { 
    public A PropertyA {get; set;} 
    public B PropertyB {get; set;}
}
```

y la clase `A` tuviera una propiedad de nombre `SomeAProperty`, entonces podrías acceder a dicha propiedad con:

```
ClassContainer container = new ClassContainer();
var propValue = container.PropertyA.SomeAProperty;
```

Comment: no quiero usar inheritancia pero supongamos que mis clases A y B son dos modelos y el container es solo un contenedor de modelos como accederia desde las vistas?

Comment: ayuda porque en razor no puedo hacer eso sino esto (arroba)model MyFirstWebsite.Models.Modelo pero quiero hacer esto (arroba)model MyFirstWebsite.Models.Modelo.Receta pero no me da esa opcion D: me falta escribir algo en Modelo? Modelo vendria ser el conteiner de modelos

Comment: ya lo consegui me faltaba cambiar el namespace y agregar un using gracias :)

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si marcas esta respuesta como aceptada (Click en el check verde del costado). Saludos :D

Comment: donde esta el check verde @fredyfx ?

Comment: justo al lado del número de las votaciones de esta respuesta :D